# Merge JavaScript objects in array with same key

Tags: javascript, arrays

What is the best way to merge array contents from JavaScript objects sharing a key in common?

How can `array` in the example below be reorganized into `output`? Here, all `value` keys (*whether an array or not*) are merged into all objects sharing the same `name` key.

```
var array = [
    {
        name: "foo1",
        value: "val1"
    }, {
        name: "foo1",
        value: [
            "val2",
            "val3"
        ]
    }, {
        name: "foo2",
        value: "val4"
    }
];

var output = [
    {
        name: "foo1",
        value: [
            "val1",
            "val2",
            "val3"
        ]
    }, {
        name: "foo2",
        value: [
            "val4"
        ]
    }
];
```

Comment: is `array` `{name:"foo1",value:"val1"}` going to be `{name:"foo1",value:["val1"]}`?

Comment: @BG101 no it's not an array but if that helps I can make it beforehand

Comment: Have you tried using jQuery's extend() method ? Or are you trying to write your own merging script ? So something like this maybe: `var newArray = $.extend({}, array, output);`

Comment: Is there a specific way you're trying to merge the content, or would `$.extend()` suffice ?

Comment: @ZachPerkitny I'm not sure $.extend() would suffice because I do have to deal with arrays within the key values.

Comment: Give me an example of how you want it to be merged

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Here is one option:-

```js
var array = [{
  name: "foo1",
  value: "val1"
}, {
  name: "foo1",
  value: ["val2", "val3"]
}, {
  name: "foo2",
  value: "val4"
}];

var output = [];

array.forEach(function(item) {
  var existing = output.filter(function(v, i) {
    return v.name == item.name;
  });
  if (existing.length) {
    var existingIndex = output.indexOf(existing[0]);
    output[existingIndex].value = output[existingIndex].value.concat(item.value);
  } else {
    if (typeof item.value == 'string')
      item.value = [item.value];
    output.push(item);
  }
});

console.dir(output);
```

Comment: My `key` and `value` name are different. and I am getting confused because here the `value` name in input object is `value` and the parameter name you have taken in the `forEach` loop is also named value. Please make my confusion clear. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry @ArpitMeena, only now seen your request in the comments. I've changed it to `item` to help in future.

Comment: what if i have an array with multiple objects all have share one same key , but this key is unknow, for example one of the objects structure is `{
 "127.0.0.1" : 1,
    "127.0.0.2" : 1,
    "127.0.0.3" : 1,
    "127.0.0.4" : 1,
}` and the second object `{
 "127.0.0.1" : 1000,
    "127.0.0.2" : 1000,
    "127.0.0.3" : 1000,
    "127.0.0.4" : 1000,
}`, how to merge them so the output, be something lke this `{"127.0.0.1": 1, "my-custom-key": 1000}, second obj etc....`. **ps** the values could be different i just made a simple example.

Answer (score 20):

Here is another way of achieving that goal:

```js
var array = [{
  name: "foo1",
  value: "val1"
}, {
  name: "foo1",
  value: [
    "val2",
    "val3"
  ]
}, {
  name: "foo2",
  value: "val4"
}];

var output = array.reduce(function(o, cur) {

  // Get the index of the key-value pair.
  var occurs = o.reduce(function(n, item, i) {
    return (item.name === cur.name) ? i : n;
  }, -1);

  // If the name is found,
  if (occurs >= 0) {

    // append the current value to its list of values.
    o[occurs].value = o[occurs].value.concat(cur.value);

    // Otherwise,
  } else {

    // add the current item to o (but make sure the value is an array).
    var obj = {
      name: cur.name,
      value: [cur.value]
    };
    o = o.concat([obj]);
  }

  return o;
}, []);

console.log(output);
```

Comment: What to do In case If I need to add the vaue as an object ?

Answer (score 15):

**2021 version**

- Using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to aggregate data.
- Using [`logical nullish assignment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment) only assigns if `acc[name]` is [nullish](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Nullish) (`null or undefined`).
- Using [`Array.isArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) to determines whether the passed value is an `Array`.

```js
var arrays = [{ name: "foo1",value: "val1" }, {name: "foo1", value: ["val2", "val3"] }, {name: "foo2",value: "val4"}];

const result = arrays.reduce((acc, {name, value}) => {
  acc[name] ??= {name: name, value: []};
  if(Array.isArray(value)) // if it's array type then concat 
    acc[name].value = acc[name].value.concat(value);
  else
    acc[name].value.push(value);
  
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(Object.values(result));
```

Comment: Hi, newbie here. What does `??=` mean?

Comment: Hi @MekelIlyasa, it means `logical nullish assignment`. It equals checking condition `if(!acc[name]) acc[name] = {name: name, value: []}`

Answer (score 11):

Using [lodash](https://lodash.com/)

```js
var array = [{name:"foo1",value:"val1"},{name:"foo1",value:["val2","val3"]},{name:"foo2",value:"val4"}];

function mergeNames (arr) {
    return _.chain(arr).groupBy('name').mapValues(function (v) {
        return _.chain(v).pluck('value').flattenDeep();
    }).value();
}

console.log(mergeNames(array));
```

Comment: simplified version and also pluck now should be map : 

`const mergeNames = arr => _.chain(arr).groupBy('name').mapValues(v => _.chain(v).map('value').flattenDeep()).value();

console.log(mergeNames(array));`

Comment: The data is coming in 

'2021-04-14': LodashWrapper {
    __wrapped__: LazyWrapper {
      __wrapped__: [LodashWrapper],
      __actions__: [Array],
      __dir__: 1,
      __filtered__: false,
      __iteratees__: [Array],
      __takeCount__: 4294967295,
      __views__: []
    },
    __actions__: [ [Object] ],
    __chain__: true,
    __index__: 0,
    __values__: undefined
  }

this format.

how to transform it in array format ?

Answer (score 9):

Here is a version using an ES6 Map:

```js
const arrays = [{ name: "foo1",value: "val1" }, {name: "foo1", value: ["val2", "val3"] }, {name: "foo2",value: "val4"}];

const map = new Map(arrays.map(({name, value}) => [name, { name, value: [] }])); 
for (let {name, value} of arrays) map.get(name).value.push(...[value].flat());
console.log([...map.values()]);
```

Answer (score 4):

Using reduce:

```
var mergedObj = array.reduce((acc, obj) => {
    if (acc[obj.name]) {
       acc[obj.name].value = acc[obj.name].value.isArray ? 
       acc[obj.name].value.concat(obj.value) : 
       [acc[obj.name].value].concat(obj.value);

    } else {
      acc[obj.name] = obj;
    }

    return acc;
}, {});

let output = [];
for (let prop in mergedObj) {
  output.push(mergedObj[prop]) 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It's been a while since this question was asked, but I thought I'd chime in as well. For functions like this that execute a basic function you'll want to use over and over, I prefer to avoid longer-written functions and loops if I can help it and develop the function as a one-liner using shallow Array.prototype functions like `.map()` and some other ES6+ goodies like `Object.entries()` and `Object.fromEntries()`. Combining all these, we can execute a function like this relatively easily.

First, I take in however many objects you pass to the function as a rest parameter and prepend that with an empty object we'll use to collect all the keys and values.

```js
[{}, ...objs]
```

Next, I use the `.map()` Array prototype function paired with `Object.entries()` to loop through all the entries of each object, and any sub-array elements each contains and then either set the empty object's key to that value if it has not yet been declared, or I push the new values to the object key if it has been declared.

```js
[{},...objs].map((e,i,a) => i ? Object.entries(e).map(f => (a[0][f[0]] ? a[0][f[0]].push(...([f[1]].flat())) : (a[0][f[0]] = [f[1]].flat()))) : e)[0]
```

Finally, to replace any single-element-arrays with their contained value, I run another `.map()` function on the result array using both `Object.entries()` and `Object.fromEntries()`, similar to how we did before.

```js
let getMergedObjs = (...objs) => Object.fromEntries(Object.entries([{},...objs].map((e,i,a) => i ? Object.entries(e).map(f => (a[0][f[0]] ? a[0][f[0]].push(...([f[1]].flat())) : (a[0][f[0]] = [f[1]].flat()))) : e)[0]).map(e => e.map((f,i) => i ? (f.length > 1 ? f : f[0]) : f)));
```

This will leave you with the final merged object, exactly as you prescribed it.

```js
let a = {
  a: [1,9],
  b: 1,
  c: 1
}
let b = {
  a: 2,
  b: 2
}
let c = {
  b: 3,
  c: 3,
  d: 5
}

let getMergedObjs = (...objs) => Object.fromEntries(Object.entries([{},...objs].map((e,i,a) => i ? Object.entries(e).map(f => (a[0][f[0]] ? a[0][f[0]].push(...([f[1]].flat())) : (a[0][f[0]] = [f[1]].flat()))) : e)[0]).map(e => e.map((f,i) => i ? (f.length > 1 ? f : f[0]) : f)));

getMergedObjs(a,b,c); // { a: [ 1, 9, 2 ], b: [ 1, 2, 3 ], c: [ 1, 3 ], d: 5 }
```

Answer (score 4):

#### Use lodash "uniqWith". As shown below

```
let _ = require("lodash");

var array = [
  { name: "foo1", value: "1" },
  { name: "foo1", value: "2" },
  { name: "foo2", value: "3" },
  { name: "foo1", value: "4" }
];

let merged = _.uniqWith(array, (pre, cur) => {
  if (pre.name == cur.name) {
    cur.value = cur.value + "," + pre.value;
    return true;
  }
  return false;
});

console.log(merged);
// output:  [{ name: "foo1", value: "1,2,4" }, { name: "foo2", value: "3" }];
```

Comment: how would I go about doing exactly this, but get the sum of foo1 values to be 7? (1+2+4)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```js
var array = [{name:"foo1",value:"val1"},{name:"foo1",value:["val2","val3"]},{name:"foo2",value:"val4"},{name:"foo2",value:"val5"}];

for(var j=0;j<array.length;j++){
  var current = array[j];
  for(var i=j+1;i<array.length;i++){
    if(current.name = array[i].name){
      if(!isArray(current.value))
        current.value = [ current.value ];
      if(isArray(array[i].value))
         for(var v=0;v<array[i].value.length;v++)
           current.value.push(array[i].value[v]);
      else
        current.value.push(array[i].value);
      array.splice(i,1);
      i++;
    }
  }
}

function isArray(myArray) {
    return myArray.constructor.toString().indexOf("Array") > -1;
}

document.write(JSON.stringify(array));
```

Comment: this is foolproof, but it's the traditional brute force method that I'm trying to get around.

Comment: Yeah, but I did not use "endless" loops :-), I only used two loops and more importantly, I worked directly on the `array` variable eliminating the need for another `output` variable which makes it more memory efficient. However, I also liked the two answers from BG101 and Hunan, so I upvoted them.

Answer (score 3):

> This work too !

```js
      var array = [
        {
          name: "foo1",
          value: "val1",
        },
        {
          name: "foo1",
          value: ["val2", "val3"],
        },
        {
          name: "foo2",
          value: "val4",
        },
      ];
      let arr2 = [];
      array.forEach((element) => { // remove duplicate name
        let match = arr2.find((r) => r.name == element.name);
        if (match) {
        } else {
          arr2.push({ name: element.name, value: [] });
        }
      });
      arr2.map((item) => {
        array.map((e) => {
          if (e.name == item.name) {
            if (typeof e.value == "object") { //lets map if value is an object
              e.value.map((z) => {
                item.value.push(z);
              });
            } else {
              item.value.push(e.value);
            }
          }
        });
      });
      console.log(arr2);
```

Comment: How could you Add the values of foo1? Basically add `val1, val2, and val3` into 1 value?

Comment: i'm using temp arr2 to save the value, then mapping them again to see is an object, then i create an array on it, if not an object/array i push the value to it @jedLancer

Answer (score 2):

```
const exampleObj = [{
  year: 2016,
  abd: 123
}, {
  year: 2016,
  abdc: 123
}, {
  year: 2017,
  abdcxc: 123
}, {
  year: 2017,
  abdcxcx: 123
}];
const listOfYears = [];
const finalObj = [];
exampleObj.map(sample => {    
  listOfYears.push(sample.year);
});
const uniqueList = [...new Set(listOfYears)];
uniqueList.map(list => {   
  finalObj.push({
    year: list
  });
});
exampleObj.map(sample => {    
  const sampleYear = sample.year;  
  finalObj.map((obj, index) => {     
    if (obj.year === sampleYear) {        
      finalObj[index] = Object.assign(sample, obj);       
    }  
  }); 
});
```

The final object be [{"year":2016,"abdc":123,"abd":123},{"year":2017,"abdcxcx":123,"abdcxc":123}]

Answer (score 2):

try this  :

```js
    var array = [
      {
          name: "foo1",
          value: "val1"
      }, {
          name: "foo1",
          value: [
              "val2",
              "val3"
          ]
      }, {
          name: "foo2",
          value: "val4"
      }
  ];
  
  var output = [
      {
          name: "foo1",
          value: [
              "val1",
              "val2",
              "val3"
          ]
      }, {
          name: "foo2",
          value: [
              "val4"
          ]
      }
  ];

  bb = Object.assign( {}, array, output );

console.log(bb) ;
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const array = [{ name: "foo1", value: "val1" }, {name: "foo1", value: ["val2", "val3"] }, {name: "foo2", value: "val4"}];
const start = array.reduce((object, {name}) => ({...object, [name]: []}), {});
const result = array.reduce((object, {name, value}) => ({...object, [name]: [object[name], [value]].flat(2)}), start);
const output = Object.entries(result).map(([name, value]) => ({name: name, value: value}));
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for a quick, almost "one-liner" answer in this thread, provided that this is a trivial but common exercise.

I couldn't find any for my like. The other answers are fine but I am not much into boilerplate.

So, let me add one, then:

```
o = array.reduce((m,{name:n,value:v})=>({...m,[n]:[...m[n]||[],v].flat(1)}),{})
output = Object.entries(o).map(([n,v])=>({name:n,value:v}))
```

```js
var array = [
  { name: "foo1", value: "val1"}, 
  { name: "foo1", value: ["val2","val3"] }, 
  { name: "foo2", value: "val4" }
]

o=array.reduce((m,{name:n,value:v})=>({...m,[n]:[...m[n]||[],v].flat(1)}),{})
output=Object.entries(o).map(([n,v])=>({name:n,value:v}))
    
console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

A much more easier approach is this 2022:

```
  var array = [
        {
            name: "foo1",
            value: "val1"
        }, {
            name: "foo1",
            value: [
                "val2",
                "val3"
            ]
        }, {
            name: "foo2",
            value: "val4"
        }
    ];
    
    var output = [
        {
            name: "foo1",
            value: [
                "val1",
                "val2",
                "val3"
            ]
        },
        {
            name: "foo2",
            value: [
                "val4"
            ]
        }
    ];
    
    function mergeBasedOnKey(list){
      let c = Object.values(list.reduce((a, b) => {
    
        a[b.name] = a[b.name] || {name: b.name, value: []}
        if(typeof(b['value']) == "string"){
          a[b.name].value.push(b['value'])
        }
        else{
          a[b.name].value = [...a[b.name].value, ...b.value]
        }
    
        return a
    
      }, {}))
      return c
    }
   let ans = mergeBasedOnKey(array)
   console.log(ans)
```

Comment: you are a life saver! very cool way to achieve this! Literally I tried all answers those are good. but this is awesome thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone like me who landed here looking for a solution to a very similar issue...

My scenario was a bit different...

This was my solution using `_.mergeWith`

```js
// pre grouped array with _.groupBy
const source = {
    obj1: [{label: null, count: null }, {label: null, count: 10 }, {label: 'value1', count: null }],
    obj2: [{label: 'value2', count: 5 }, {label: null, count: null }],
    obj3: [{label: null, count: null }, {label: null, count: null }, {label: null, count: 15 }, {label: 'value3', count: null }],
    obj4: [{label: null, count: null }, {label: null, count: null }, {label: null, count: null }, {label: null, count: null }],
}

function combineObjects(key, source) {
    // spread the source array so not to mutate the original source with `.shift()` when getting the first object to merge with
    return _.mergeWith([...source[key]].shift(), ...source[key], (objValue, srcValue) => {
        if (srcValue !== null) return srcValue
        return objValue
    })
}

const combinedObjects = Object.keys(source).map(key => combineObjects(key, source))

// combinedObjects -> [{label: 'value1', count: 10 },{label: 'value2', count: 5 },{label: 'value3', count: 15 }, {label: null, count: null}]
```

Hope this might help someone with a similar scenario I faced.