# merge 2 array into new array after matching their content javascript

Tags: javascript

I have 2 arrays, and I want a new array based upon condition that the content of these 2 arrays matched

```js
arr1 = [{
    package_id: 'aabbccdd',
    level: 2
  },
  {
    package_id: 'xycd21',
    level: 3
  }
]

arr2 = [{
    package_id: 'aabbccdd',
    level: 1
  },
  {
    package_id: 'zcb21',
    level: 5
  }]

mergedArray = [{
    package_id: 'aabbccdd',
    arr1Level: 2,
    arr2Level: 1
  },
  {
    package_id: 'xycd21',
    arr1Level: 3,
    arr2Level: 0
  },
  {
    package_id: 'zcb21',
    arr1Level: 0,
    arr2Level: 5
  }]
```

So if package_id is to be checked in both arrays. And if found in either array, new array pushed one element where level from both array is mentioned against package_id.

I just could not figure out the logic to do that. If that can be done by lodash kindly tell me.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Even an algo would be great if you share

Comment: You're expected to try to **write the code yourself**.If you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Stack Overflow isn't a coding service.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33850412/merge-javascript-objects-in-array-with-same-key. Its not exact duplicate so not voting to close but should give you what you need to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily solve this using loops like i did here:

```js
var arr1 = [{
    package_id: 'aabbccdd',
    level: 2
  },
  {
    package_id: 'xycd21',
    level: 3
  }
];

var arr2 = [{
    package_id: 'aabbccdd',
    level: 1
  },
  {
    package_id: 'zcb21',
    level: 5
  }
];
  
var mergedArr = [];
var tempObj = {};

for(var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++){
  tempObj.package_id = arr1[i].package_id;
  tempObj.arr1Level = arr1[i].level;
  tempObj.arr2Level = 0;
  for(var k = 0; k < arr2.length; k++){
    if(arr1[i].package_id === arr2[k].package_id){
      tempObj.arr2Level = arr2[k].level;
    }
  }
  mergedArr.push(tempObj);
  tempObj = {};
}

for(i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++){
  var isNew = true;
  for(k = 0; k < mergedArr.length; k++){
    if(arr2[i].package_id === mergedArr[k].package_id){
      isNew = false;
    }
  }
  if(isNew){
    tempObj.package_id = arr2[i].package_id;
    tempObj.arr2Level = arr2[i].level;
    tempObj.arr1Level = 0;
    mergedArr.push(tempObj);
    tempObj = {};
  }
}

console.log(mergedArr);
```

Comment: Dear, Thanks a lot, it works. And I also agree to other people view that there should be no spoon feeding. But believe me I am working on an Ionic2 project and wrote almost 3500 lines of codes, with and without help. I just could not figure out the logic for this code. thanks a lot again.

Answer (score 1):

You can first add both arrays to one array and then use `reduce()` and `forEach()` to create new array of objects. Also you can use another object to group elements by `package_id`

```js
var arr1 = [{ package_id: 'aabbccdd', level: 2 }, { package_id: 'xycd21', level: 3 }];
var arr2 = [{ package_id: 'aabbccdd', level: 1 }, { package_id: 'zcb21', level: 5 }];

var o = {}
var arrays = [arr1, arr2]
var keys = Array.from(Array(arrays.length), (e, i) => ({['arr' + (i + 1) + 'Level']: 0}))

var result = arrays.reduce(function(r, a, i) {
  a.forEach(function(e) {
    if (!o[e.package_id]) {
      o[e.package_id] = Object.assign({}, {package_id: e.package_id}, ...keys)
      r.push(o[e.package_id]);
    }
    o[e.package_id]['arr' + (i + 1) + 'Level'] = e.level;
  })
  return r;
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a structure approach with dynamic keys for different arrays and use the keys as help for generating default values.

```js
var arr1 = [{ package_id: 'aabbccdd', level: 2 }, { package_id: 'xycd21', level: 3 }],
    arr2 = [{ package_id: 'aabbccdd', level: 1 }, { package_id: 'zcb21', level: 5 }],
    keys = [{ level: 'arr1level' }, { level: 'arr2level' }],
    result = [arr1, arr2].reduce(function (hash) {
        return function (r, a, i) {
            a.forEach(function (b) {
                if (!hash[b.package_id]) {
                    hash[b.package_id] = { package_id: b.package_id },
                    r.push(hash[b.package_id]);
                }
                keys.forEach(function (key) {
                    Object.keys(key).forEach(function (k) {
                        hash[b.package_id][key[k]] = 0;
                    });
                });
                Object.keys(b).forEach(function (k) {
                    var key = keys[i][k] || k;
                    hash[b.package_id][key] = b[k];
                });
            });
            return r;
        };
    }(Object.create(null)), []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```