# Merge nested array of objects by unique property and array

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js, lodash

I am finding a difficult time finding a solution for multiple levels of push / merging with Lodash and Underscore. Trying to avoid some messy nested loops with JS.

Here's an example of how I need to merge.

```
const arr = [
  {
    level : 'test',
    items : [1, 2, 3]
  },
  {
    level : 'tests',
    items : [1, 2, 3]
  }
];

const obj = {
  level : 'test',
  items : [4, 5, 6]
};


/* Output:
  [
    {
      level : 'test',
      items : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    },
    {
      level : 'tests',
      items : [1, 2, 3]
    }
  ];
*/
```

The `obj` level matches `arr[0]`, and so the items array should merge.  New, or unique levels should push to the array as a new object.

Is there a way I could achieve this through some combination of [_.groupBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#groupBy) and [_.mergeWith](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#mergeWith) of Lodash?  So far, I have gotten it to merge into a single array with two objects from the two respective unique levels, but when the items arrays merge it ends up with `[4, 5, 6]`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge javascript objects in array with same key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33850412/merge-javascript-objects-in-array-with-same-key)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `array#find` to search for an object with same `level` value. Then, for a successful match `array#concat` items.

```js
const arr = [ { level : 'test', items : [1, 2, 3] }, { level : 'tests', items : [1, 2, 3] } ]; 
const obj = { level : 'test', items : [4, 5, 6] };
const result = arr.find(o => o.level === obj.level);
if(result)
  result.items = result.items.concat(obj.items);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Thank you for providing an explanation with yours, so I'll accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const arr = [
  {
    level : 'test',
    items : [1, 2, 3]
  },
  {
    level : 'tests',
    items : [1, 2, 3]
  }
];

const obj = {
  level : 'test',
  items : [4, 5, 6]
};


/* Output:
  [
    {
      level : 'test',
      items : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    },
    {
      level : 'tests',
      items : [1, 2, 3]
    }
  ];
*/

const newArr = _.map(arr, (val) => {
  return !_.isEqual(val.level, obj.level) ? val 
    : _.assign({}, val, {
      items: _.concat(val.items, obj.items)
    });
});

console.log(newArr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to function.  I've accepted another answer, so thank you for your help anyway th3n3wguy

Comment: @JSess => I updated the code because I was missing the external library and a closing bracket.

Comment: The main difference between my answer and your accepted answer is that mine is using Lodash, which is what you originally asked for. Lol.

Comment: I know, but I implemented his first and it worked.  I can't accept multiple answers or I would.  I upvoted you, though.

Comment: @JSess => That is fully-understandable. I should've made sure that my code was 100% functional first. Either way, I am glad that you found a working answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
arr.map((e)=>{e.level === obj.level && e.items.push(...obj.items);return e})
```

let me know if it works

Comment: This does work, but I have accepted the other answer already.  I appreciate your help, Saikat Hajra.