# How to merge the property with same key in two object array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

There are two object array,  some of them have the same key, I'd like to merge the same key in the first array. I have pasted my code.I used nested loop, but the performance was bad `O(n²)`. Maybe I need another method to enhance performance.**(I can't use ES6 for some reason, so I'll appreciate if it is the ES5 method.)**

```
var people = [
    {
       id: "001",
       name: "David",
       age: 29
    },
    {
       id: "002",
       name: "Lucia",
       age: 41    
    },
    {
       id: "003",
       name: "Steve",
       age: 18
    }
];

var address = [
    {
        id: "001",
        city: "Barcelona"
    },
    {
        id: "002",
        city: "Paris"
    },
    {

    },
    {
        id: "003",
        city: "Tokyo"
    },
    {
        id: "004",
        city: "Barcelona"
    }
];
```

---

**My code**

```
people.forEach(function(item) {
  var id = item.id;
    address.forEach(function(location) {
      if (location.id == id) {
        item.address = location.address
      }
     });
});
```

---

**Result**

```
var people = [
    {
       id: "001",
       name: "David",
       age: 29,
       city: "Barcelona"
    },
    {
       id: "002",
       name: "Lucia",
       age: 41,
       city: "Paris"    
    },
    {
       id: "003",
       name: "Steve",
       age: 18,
       city: "Tokyo"
    }
];
```

The new people array is I preferred.

Comment: Care to format you question properly

Comment: will the sizes of the two arrays be equal ?

Comment: Have you tried to iterate over array and merge the items? Please add your code in the question. [edit].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge javascript objects in array with same key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33850412/merge-javascript-objects-in-array-with-same-key)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) with all addresses and then map new object with extended properties of the map.

This approach takes all properties of `address` objects.

```js
var people = [{ id: "001", name: "David", age: 29 }, { id: "002", name: "Lucia", age: 41 }, { id: "003", name: "Steve", age: 18 }],
    address = [{ id: "001", city: "Barcelona" }, { id: "002", city: "Paris" }, {}, { id: "003", city: "Tokyo" }, { id: "004", city: "Barcelona" }],
    map = new Map(address.map(o => [o.id, o])),
    result = people.map(o => Object.assign({}, o, map.get(o.id)));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: so we can pass an Array like object into the map class constructor and it will make a map for us, that's nice

Comment: you could take any iterable.

Answer (score 3):

Make a `Map` with cities by id, and use it when iterating over the `people` array to find out the city:

```
let cities = new Map(address.map(a => [a.id, a.city]));
let people2 = people.map(p => ( {...p, city: cities.get(p.id)} ));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Array#map` to iterate over `people`, and `Array#find` to find the corresponding address from `id` within iterations:

```js
const people = [{id: "001",name: "David",age: 29 },{ id: "002", name: "Lucia", age: 41
},{ id: "003", name: "Steve", age: 18 }],
  address = [{ id: "001", city: "Barcelona" },{ id: "002", city: "Paris" },{ },{ id: "003", city: "Tokyo" },{ id: "004", city: "Barcelona" }];

console.log(
  people.map(p => ({
    ...p,
    ...address.find(a => (p.id === a.id))
  }))
);
```

However, that's supposing that the properties' name of `address`'s items are not the same as `people`'s ones.

Answer (score 1):

The code below is not tested but it should work

```
// create an object to store them
const mergedItems = {};

// merge the 2 arrays so you only map them once (just for shorter code)
people.concat(address).map(entity => {
  // add each entity on the object and id as a key
  mergedItems[entity.id] = {

    // if the key exist, it will merge it with the new entity
    ...mergedItems[entity.id],
    ...entity,
  }
)

// this is your merged items
// Object.values will convert it from object to array
const finalItems = Object.values(mergedItems);
```

I used map instead of for loop because it is faster: https://codeburst.io/javascript-map-vs-foreach-f38111822c0f

Answer (score 0):

I have used Object.assign method to add values from address

```
   var people = [{ id: "001", name: "David", age: 29 }, { id: "002", name: "Lucia", age: 41 }, { id: "003", name: "Steve", age: 18 }],
        address = [{ id: "001", city: "Barcelona" }, { id: "002", city: "Paris" }, {}, { id: "003", city: "Tokyo" }, { id: "004", city: "Barcelona" }];

        people.forEach(function(item,pos){
            Object.assign(item,{},address[address.findIndex(o=>o.id == item.id)]);
        });
        console.log(people);
```