# Merge two objects which have same keys and convert values to array

Tags: javascript

```
var obj1 = {name: “John”, hobby: “Football”}

var obj2 = {hobby: “Basketball”}
```

These are my two object. I want to  merge them and my result will be

```
   var obj1 = {name: “John”, hobby :[“Foootbal”,”Basketball”]}
```

How can ı do this ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge javascript objects in array with same key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33850412/merge-javascript-objects-in-array-with-same-key)

Comment: This doesn't looks like a merge. We could consider a merge if both `obj1` and `obj2` are strictly the type. In this case, you could **reduce** it in a new type

Answer (score 4):

```js
var obj1 = {name: "John", hobby: "Football"}

var obj2 = {hobby: "Basketball"}
var obj3 = {hobby: "Tennis"}

const merge = (obj1, obj2) => {
    Object.keys(obj1).forEach(key => { if (obj2[key]) obj1[key] = [...[obj1[key]], obj2[key]].flat() })
}

merge(obj1, obj2)
merge(obj1, obj3)

console.log(obj1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much.. How can ı do dymanic this code ? I want to add some values in hobby dynamic ?

Comment: Put the operative line in a function.  But it cannot reprocess data, it assumes you have only comparable strings as values.  So if you re-ran the merge, you would get an array in an array.

Comment: Update code to dynamically merge objects

Answer (score 0):

```js
const obj1 = {name: "John", hobby: "Football"}

const obj2 = {hobby: "Basketball"}

const obj3 = {}
for (const key in obj1){
  if (obj2[key] === undefined){
    obj3[key] = obj1[key]    
  }else{    
    obj3[key] = [ obj1[key], obj2[key] ]
  }
}
console.log(obj3)
```

Slightly different solution.  Does not alter original objects.