# How to merge these two arrays in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, express, lodash

Array 1:

```
[
  { _id: '01', user: 0, vendor: 1, driver: 0 },
  { _id: '04', user: 2, vendor: 15, driver: 2 },
  { _id: '05', user: 24, vendor: 10, driver: 1 },
  { _id: '06', user: 0, vendor: 18, driver: 0 }
]
```

Array 2:

```
[
  { _id: '04', order: 20 },
  { _id: '05', order: 28 },
  { _id: '06', order: 3 },
  { _id: '08', order: 1 }
]
```

I need output like this

```
[
  { _id: '01', user: 0, vendor: 1, driver: 0 },
  { _id: '04', user: 2, vendor: 15, driver: 2, order: 20 },
  { _id: '05', user: 24, vendor: 10, driver: 1, order: 28 },
  { _id: '06', user: 0, vendor: 18, driver: 0, order: 3 },
  { _id: '08', user: 0, vendor: 0, driver: 0, order: 1 }
]
```

I am using lodash to merge array,

```
let merge = _.merge(arr1, arr2);
```

but, getting this output like this

```
 [
  { _id: '04', user: 0, vendor: 1, driver: 0, order: 20 },
  { _id: '05', user: 2, vendor: 15, driver: 2, order: 28 },
  { _id: '06', user: 24, vendor: 10, driver: 1, order: 4 },
  { _id: '06', user: 0, vendor: 18, driver: 0 }
]
```

please help me to do that

Comment: You can merge the arrays and apply an answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33850412/merge-javascript-objects-in-array-with-same-key

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this result using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```js
const arr1 = [
  { _id: "01", user: 0, vendor: 1, driver: 0 },
  { _id: "04", user: 2, vendor: 15, driver: 2 },
  { _id: "05", user: 24, vendor: 10, driver: 1 },
  { _id: "06", user: 0, vendor: 18, driver: 0 },
];

const arr2 = [
  { _id: "04", order: 20 },
  { _id: "05", order: 28 },
  { _id: "06", order: 4 },
];

const result = arr1.map((obj) => {
  const objInArr2 = arr2.find((o) => o._id === obj._id);
  if (objInArr2) return { ...obj, ...objInArr2 };
  else return { ...obj };
});

console.log(result);
```

**EDIT: If some object exists in `arr2` but not in `arr1`**

```js
const arr1 = [
  { _id: "01", user: 0, vendor: 1, driver: 0 },
  { _id: "04", user: 2, vendor: 15, driver: 2 },
  { _id: "05", user: 24, vendor: 10, driver: 1 },
  { _id: "06", user: 0, vendor: 18, driver: 0 },
];

const arr2 = [
  { _id: "04", order: 20 },
  { _id: "05", order: 28 },
  { _id: "06", order: 3 },
  { _id: "08", order: 1 },
];

const result = arr1.map((obj) => {
  const objInArr2 = arr2.find((o) => o._id === obj._id);
  if (objInArr2) return { ...obj, ...objInArr2 };
  else return { ...obj };
});

arr2.forEach((obj) => {
  const isExist = result.find((o) => o._id === obj._id);
  if (!isExist) result.push({ user: 0, vendor: 0, driver: 0, ...obj });
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: It is working, what is arr2 has more object which is greater then 06, its not returning the value

Comment: Edit the question and what is your desired result?

Comment: Do you want to add the object in the final result, if it exists in `arr2` but not in `arr1`. Is that so?

Comment: allow me 2-3 min

Comment: Okay no problem

Comment: @Nick updated. Please verify if this is what you want...

Answer (score 1):

```js
let arr1 = [
  { _id: '01', user: 0, vendor: 1, driver: 0 },
  { _id: '04', user: 2, vendor: 15, driver: 2 },
  { _id: '05', user: 24, vendor: 10, driver: 1 },
  { _id: '06', user: 0, vendor: 18, driver: 0 }
];

let arr2 = [
  { _id: '04', order: 20 },
  { _id: '05', order: 28 },
  { _id: '06', order: 4 }
];

arr2.forEach(e => {
 let obj = arr1.find(a => a._id === e._id);
 if(obj)
  obj.order = e.order
});

console.log(arr1);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `lodash`, try to use [mergeWith](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#mergeWith) instead. Make sure `customizer` option is used.

Another way https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=merge%20deep

Answer (score 0):

Put the second array into a Map for efficient look ups by `_id`, then map first array

```js
const arr1=[
  { _id: '01', user: 0, vendor: 1, driver: 0 },
  { _id: '04', user: 2, vendor: 15, driver: 2 },
  { _id: '05', user: 24, vendor: 10, driver: 1 },
  { _id: '06', user: 0, vendor: 18, driver: 0 }
]

const arr2=[
  { _id: '04', order: 20 },
  { _id: '05', order: 28 },
  { _id: '06', order: 4 }
]

const arr2Map = new Map(arr2.map(({_id,...r}) => [_id, r]))

const res = arr1.map(e => Object.assign({}, e, arr2Map.get(e._id)))

console.log(res)
```