# How to merge object with same key in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My data is shaped like: `[{size: ["large", "medium"]}, {color: ["red", "green"]}]`

Form Page:

```
const optionSubmit = (e) => {
    const name = e.target.name;

    const storeValue = { [name]: productValue };
    addData(storeValue);
};
```

`formContext` page:

```
const addData= (newData) => {
    setData(() => [...data, newData]);
}
```

The problem is when I change size object example its showing like:
[
{size: ["large", "medium"]},
{color: ["red", "green"]},
{size: ["large", "medium", "small"]}
]

I want this array to become like this:

```
[{color: ["red", "green"]},{size: ["large", "medium", small]}]
```

Comment: Can you show us the code that you use to alter that object?

Comment: edited my code please look

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge JavaScript objects in array with same key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33850412/merge-javascript-objects-in-array-with-same-key)

Comment: no i have tried it but no result found

Answer (score 2):

You are taking your *existing* object and spreading it into a new array, and then adding the `newData` into that new array too. That is why you see this behavior.

Instead you can do this a couple of ways but something like this using [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```
const addData= (newData) => {
  setData(() => Object.assign({}, data, newData};
}
```

Or if your `newData` is an object only containing the `{size: []}` then you could just do this:

```
const addData= (newData) => {
  setData(() => {...data, ...newData};
}
```

Comment: data is an array with but new data is coming as an object
example: 
[{color: ["red", "green"]},{size: ["large", "medium", "small"]}]

Comment: Thank you sir first one worked

Answer (score 0):

```js
const myArr = [
    {size: ["large", "medium"]}, 
    {color: ["red", "green"]}, 
    {size: ["large", "medium", "small"]}
   ];
const result = [];
  myArr.forEach(e=>{
    const key = Object.keys(e)[0];
    const i = result.findIndex(r=>Object.keys(r)[0]==key);
    if(i>=0){
    result[i]= {...result[i],...e};
    }else{
    result.push(e)
    }
}) 
console.log(result)
```

Comment: updated the answer now check.

Comment: i have find an easy way thats why i didn't tried it but thanks for helping