# I want to modify an array in Javascript in a very specific way and i don't know how to

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

so this is my array:

```
0: {universityYear: 'Anul universitar 2022-2023', name: 'Pimpulsul'}
1: {universityYear: 'Anul universitar 2021-2022', name: 'Evrikaul'}
2: {universityYear: 'Anul universitar 2021-2022', name: 'Po'}
```

and I want to obtain:

```
0: {universityYear: 'Anul universitar 2022-2023', name: ['Pimpulsul'] }
1: {universityYear: 'Anul universitar 2021-2022', name: ['Evrikaul', 'Po'] }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge JavaScript objects in array with same key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33850412/merge-javascript-objects-in-array-with-same-key)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `reduce`:

```js
let arr = [
    {universityYear: 'Anul universitar 2022-2023', name: 'Pimpulsul'},
    {universityYear: 'Anul universitar 2021-2022', name: 'Evrikaul'},
    {universityYear: 'Anul universitar 2021-2022', name: 'Po'}
];

let newArr = arr.reduce((out, cv, ci, re) => {
    let targetIndex = out.findIndex(item => item.universityYear == cv.universityYear);
    if(targetIndex > -1)
      out[targetIndex].name.push(cv.name);
    else
      out.push({...cv, name: [cv.name]})

    return out;
}, []);

console.log(newArr)
```

Comment: thank you, it works exactly the way I wanted

Comment: Your welcome, please click on the '✔'